# A word to replace "opposé à ma pensée"

Tags: vocabulaire, synonymes

I am writing a text and I need to use a rich vocabulary. I have a sentence saying "son opinion contraire à la mienne" and I was wondering if a word existed that mean "contraire à ce que je pense" or "qui s'oppose à ma pensée"

Answer (score 2):

The word "**antagonisme**" can be used after it has been made clear that something that can embody the nature of  "antagonisme" (thought, action, attitude, sens of humour) is being spoken about.

- Il venait de faire sous les yeux de son tuteur exactement ce que celui-ci lui avait expliqué comme étant contraire aux normes. Son antagonisme semblait provenir d'un besoin de contredire et d'irriter simplement pour le plaisir qu'il trouvait à voir la déception qu'il causait aux gens.
- Jean et Pierre ne voyaient pas les choses du même œil tous les deux ; quand Jean dit à Pierre que le meilleur moment pour des vacances parfaites était le mois d'aout, l'antagonisme habituel de ce dernier se manifesta aussitôt par la réplique que, lui, les considérait ne pouvoir être idéales qu'entre juin et juillet.

You can also qualify a term by means of the corresponding adjective.

- **actes antagonistes, attitude antagoniste**
- Jean ne pouvait plus discuter avec Pierre, la pensée antagoniste de ce dernier l'exaspérait.

You can also use "**contrariant**" as an adjective;

- Leur esprit contrariant ne facilite pas la camaraderie.
- Les pensées contrariantes de cette dame lui ont valu l'hostilité de certaines de ses collègues.

Answer (score 0):

Question d'intensité : si c'est tellement opposé à ma pensée que je ne peux pas l'accepter sans combattre, ça devient "révoltant".
"Face à moi, il tenait des propos révoltants"